# Remove cells containing zero but keep the row

Tags: r

Like the title says

The dataset contains a ID number with multiple columns with details.
Some of the rows contain missing values (0) for one or more columns.
I want to blank the cell containing the zero but keep the whole row.

Data is like this:

df

```
ID     width     diameter     categorie
1      10        5            B
2      7         4            B  
3      0         4            B
4      7         0            B
5      0         0            B
```

Needs to be like this:

```
ID     width     diameter     categorie
1      10        5            B
2      7         4            B  
3                4            B
4      7                      B
5                             B
```

Tried `sub` and `gsub` but i both cases it also removed the zero behind hundred (100 -> 10) or any other number containing a 0.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are these numbers numeric or strings?

Comment: They are numeric at the start of the script. Later on I turn them into strings by adding "mm" to each value.

Comment: Try `df[df == 0] <- ''`

Comment: Turn it into a character matrix: `m <- as.matrix(df)`. Then you can replace zeros with empty characters: `m[m == 0] <- ""`